# I am using Ubuntu 8.10 and I want to upgrade to the latest version

Tags: upgrade, versions, 8.10

I just installed Ubuntu 8.10 (from live cd I found at my house) on my MBPro. I want to upgrade to the latest version and I don't know how.... I know this must be pretty basic but I am new at this...

Comment: possible duplicated: [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/q/91815/62483)

Comment: possible duplicated: [Will it be possible to upgrade to the latest Ubuntu from an older version](http://askubuntu.com/q/72969/62483)

Answer (score 1):

Since your installation is new, I would suggest you download an .iso of a newer version of Ubuntu and make a new installation.

Answer (score 1):

You're using an `End of Life` version of Ubuntu which is no longer supported, and the versions it could originally update to, are also no longer supported. You will have to simply install a new version instead, or attempt to go the unsupported path of updating directly to the newer version manually, by pointing the apt `sources.list` at the release you are wanting to update to, and running `apt-get dist-upgrade`. As this upgrade path is unsupported, it is untested, and may break in a manner that is very difficult to recover from. Your best option is to just install using the new version.